# What's the relationship between the importance of understanding Vedas properly and Vritrasura incident?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, indra, vritra, arthavada

Vritrasura is a demon in the Vedic and Puranic literature, who is killed by Indra.

I heard someone saying that there is some relation between this story and the importance of understanding the Vedas correctly.

What's the relationship or analogy or Arthavaada between the importance of understanding Vedas properly and Vritrasura incident?

Comment: @Shashank can you please not edit the question. Vedas are nitya so why I'm using is. And regarding "some, saying", that's even wrong gramatically. Please don't edit my question.

Comment: Kalpa procedures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why were these scriptures not
> permitted to be written down? Because the sound of the Vedas cannot
> be properly transcribed. There are sounds or phonemes that cannot be
> accurately represented in any script.
> Besides there are svaras for Vedic mantras (tonal variations, proper accentuation):"udatta"
> (raised syllable), "anudatta"(lowered syllable) and "svarita"(falling
> syllable). Mistakes in enunciation are likely even if diacritical or some
> other marks are used in the printed text. Wrong chanting will not bring
> the desired results. There is a story in the Taittiriya Samhita of the Vedas which illustrates how wrong chanting can produce results contrary to what is intended. Tvasta,
> chanted a mantra with the object of begetting a son who would be the
> slayer of Indra. But he went wrong in the intonation of some syllables. So,
> unwittingly, he prayed for a son who would be slain by Indra instead of
> one who would slay that celestial. And his prayer (that had gone wrong in
> the intonation) was answered. When the wavelength shifts even minutely
> on our radio we receive the broadcast of a different transmitting station.
> Fine-tuning has to be done to get the required station. So is the case with
> the intonation of Vedic mantras. There should not be the slightest
> mistake in the svaras. Just as we receive a different station on our radio
> when the wavelength is changed, so the result is different when we go
> wrong in the intonation.
> This is the reason why it is of the utmost importance to learn the Vedas
> by listening.
> *Hindu Dharma the Universal way of life, Pujyasri Chandrasekhara Saraswati Swami*

Vritra is the son of Tvashta. When Vishwarupa, the son of Tvashta, was slain by Indra, Tvashta performed a sacrifice with the intention of obtaining a son who could slay the King of Gods. Due to a mispronounciation, he instead obtained a son who would be slain by Indra instead. This son was Vritra. This episode  in Taittiriya Samhita 2.4.11 - 2.5.1, can be better understood through Srimad Bhagavada Purana 6.9.11

> After Viśvarūpa was killed, his father, Tvaṣṭā, performed ritualistic ceremonies to kill Indra. He offered oblations in the sacrificial fire, saying, “O enemy of Indra, flourish to kill your enemy without delay.”
>  Purport 
> (ṣaṣṭhī), and the word **indra-śatro** is called a tat-puruṣa compound (tatpuruṣa-samāsa). Unfortunately, instead of chanting the mantra short, Tvaṣṭā chanted it long, and its meaning changed from “the enemy of Indra” to “Indra, who is an enemy.” Consequently instead of an enemy of Indra’s, there emerged the body of Vṛtrāsura, of whom Indra was the enemy.
> [SB 6.9.11](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/6/9/11)

Comment: Great Answer @Athrey !!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Have awarded the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Vedas are governed by six angas if one had dechiper true meaning of vedas they should have thorough knowledge on six angas
<<
Shiksha(phonetics) vyakharana(grammar) niruktha(eytomolgy),joytisha(astrology) , chandas(meter) and Kalpa procedures

In virtaasura case shiksha gone wrong while uttering mantra

Comment: It would be really great if you could pls cite some sources :)

Comment: What questions the mathematics operation? If some one answers addition subtraction division multiplication would you ask for sources?

Comment: "In virtaasura case shiksha gone wrong while uttering mantra"
How do i assume this isn't opinion based Sir? If you could elucidate on this statement a little more by providing some background,citing references that after reading which texts you have arrived on such a conclusion,then that would make much more sense imo.I don't have a problem with the initial part of your answer!